# Paypal redirect is wrong after payment!

Tags: expresso-store, paypal

i have a very strange issue that the paypal redirect point to the wrong url in Safari and some versions of Chrome. The redirect url is correct and it work on some browsers.
But on other the redirect seems to be a wrong act url and i didn't find out how i could handle this? Any suggestions to that issue?

Best Peter

Comment: Can you elaborate. What variables are in play. Is the error with ee templates if so what is in the template. Need more info.

Comment: I don't what's wrong there.

What i used for the checkout tags is

`
{exp:store:checkout 
                form_id="register-form"
                register_member=""
                error_handling="inline"
                error_delimiters="<div class="help-box"></div>"                require="name|order_email|address1|address3|postcode|country"
                return="shop/appreciate/"
                secure="yes"
            }
`

Comment: do you have an htaccess file in play?

Comment: Yes i used one.

But i think the main problem is that in safari for example, i get an act url back like this https://www.domain.com/?ACT=52&H=b6cd1c6d46892ce04d8ed334ec2d9102&token=EC-8JG52659R7911740A&PayerID=KYC6HHRA6DLH6

instead on the correct version i get back the correct path https://www.domain.com/shop/appreciate

Comment: Anyone an idea why this could happen?

Comment: You need to be more specific to help. What happens when it redirects to the ACT url? The ACT url is correct, Store handles the PayPal response then forwards the customer to the correct page. So we need to know what happens on that page if it doesn't forward the customer on (maybe it is displaying an error message).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, i didn't find a good solution for this.
We hard coded the return url now to the store_payments.php but i don't think that's a good solution ...

```
public function redirect_to_return_url($order)
{
    $return_url = $this->EE->store_orders_model->get_order_return_url($order);
    $return_url = "https://www.domain.com/shop/appreciate";
    $this->EE->functions->redirect($return_url);

}
```

I think the problem is with the return_url.
As paremeter i set the return url to something like this in my checkout template:

```
{exp:store:checkout 
    form_id="register-form"
    register_member=""
    error_handling="inline"
    error_delimiters='<div class="help-box">|</div>'
    require="name|order_email|address1|address3|postcode|country"
    return="https://www.domain.com/shop/appreciate"
}
```

I used it with and without https://domain.com/shop/appreciate and the behavior was always the same. In the output of my developer log i saw that the return url is set sometimes twice like http://www.domain.com/http://www.domain.com in Google Chrome. I thought that this is the error and Safari can't handle a doubled url, but as i had a look into the developer log again, the return url was always my checkout template although i set the correct return_url as described above??? I don't know what's wrong or where this url come from.

Maybe you can give me a hint where the return url is set, or why safari and chrome handle this in a different way?

Any help would be really good.

Thanks

Peter

Comment: Not sure what version of EE or Store you are using, but this isn't the correct solution. If  you do this then the payment won't be marked as complete, because it won't have a chance to let Store process the payment after returning from Paypal.